# Multiple GitHub Checks with Jenkins Multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, github

I have configured Jenkins using Blue ocean multibranch pipeline and a Jenkinsfile to trigger a build when new pull request appear in a repo.

In this pipeline I have two stages that run in parallel, because they are independent tests. What I would like to achieve is to display two check results on the pull request page on Github, one for each stage.

Initially I though about creating two pipelines using two different Jenkinsfile, but it seems that multibranch plugin does not support this.

What is the correct solution to achieve this?

Comment: Ever figure this out? Ran into the same issue just now (with a regular single branch pipeline)

Comment: Unfortunately not. At the end I gave up and I access blueocean pipeline graph from the link in GitHub to check at what step it failed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll let you know if I figure something out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use plugin - https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-autostatus-plugin

The plugin can be configured to send commit status for each stage for jobs build from a multibranch project. For example:
[image]